# Leksah in NixOS 14.12 - fails to install, why?

Tags: haskell, leksah, nixos, nix

Leksah in NixOS 14.12 - unstable channel fails to install, why ?

```
[demo@nixos:~]$ nix-channel --list
nixpkgs http://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable

[demo@nixos:~]$ nix-env -i leksah
installing ‘leksah’
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/69k8c7mvz64k08z9gabh7gmcn1i265rn-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2.drv
  /nix/store/h9dxxnab1sngr2d6g1q9qj0yv35iqyzs-haskell-leksah-0.15.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/lfjh66d015dkh9kr51h5871c7gqji5na-ghc-7.10.1.drv
  /nix/store/pdpsxp33mffmq72vhk5ig8bhrrdyq7p2-leksah.drv
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2’
setupCompilerEnvironmentPhase
Build with /nix/store/bc84hdk730zcdm1c9s5yf2ahpvm51lzp-ghc-7.10.1.
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/cmrcmadl401k7sjgqwj2dz4b9jqwxnck-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2.tar.gz
source root is regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2
patching sources
compileBuildDriverPhase
setupCompileFlags: -package-db=/tmp/nix-build-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2.drv-0/package.conf.d -j1 -threaded
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Setup.lhs, /tmp/nix-build-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2.drv-0/Main.o )
Linking Setup ...
configuring
configureFlags: --verbose --prefix=/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2 --libdir=$prefix/lib/$compiler --libsubdir=$pkgid --with-gcc=gcc --package-db=/tmp/nix-build-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2.drv-0/package.conf.d --ghc-option=-optl=-Wl,-rpath=/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/lib/ghc-7.10.1/regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2 --ghc-option=-j1 --enable-split-objs --disable-library-profiling --enable-shared --enable-library-vanilla --enable-executable-dynamic --enable-tests
Configuring regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2...
Dependency array -any: using array-0.5.1.0
Dependency base >=3 && <5: using base-4.8.0.0
Dependency regex-base -any: using regex-base-0.93.2
Dependency regex-tdfa >=1.1.1: using regex-tdfa-1.2.0
Dependency text -any: using text-1.2.1.1
Using Cabal-1.22.2.0 compiled by ghc-7.10
Using compiler: ghc-7.10.1
Using install prefix:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2
Binaries installed in:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/bin
Libraries installed in:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/lib/ghc-7.10.1/regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2
Private binaries installed in:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/libexec
Data files installed in:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.1/regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2
Documentation installed in:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/share/doc/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.1/regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2
Configuration files installed in:
/nix/store/53kxzd2apkijwib78gw4mdlpxs5vllpj-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2/etc
No alex found
Using ar found on system at:
/nix/store/yxg5zsjxp1l16xk7r23rayyc18fkxynk-binutils-2.23.1/bin/ar
No c2hs found
No cpphs found
Using gcc version 4.8.4 given by user at:
/nix/store/ylj1q31a7x3pvcraxk60dyv9y4wmwcrc-gcc-wrapper-4.8.4/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.10.1 found on system at:
/nix/store/bc84hdk730zcdm1c9s5yf2ahpvm51lzp-ghc-7.10.1/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.10.1 found on system at:
/nix/store/bc84hdk730zcdm1c9s5yf2ahpvm51lzp-ghc-7.10.1/bin/ghc-pkg
No ghcjs found
No ghcjs-pkg found
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.16.0 found on system at:
/nix/store/bc84hdk730zcdm1c9s5yf2ahpvm51lzp-ghc-7.10.1/bin/haddock
No happy found
Using haskell-suite found on system at: haskell-suite-dummy-location
Using haskell-suite-pkg found on system at: haskell-suite-pkg-dummy-location
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.67 found on system at:
/nix/store/bc84hdk730zcdm1c9s5yf2ahpvm51lzp-ghc-7.10.1/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at:
/nix/store/bc84hdk730zcdm1c9s5yf2ahpvm51lzp-ghc-7.10.1/bin/hsc2hs
Using hscolour version 1.22 found on system at:
/nix/store/g6mfdhbmwm0499n88bnzd32y96gmnfn9-hscolour-1.23/bin/HsColour
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at:
/nix/store/ylj1q31a7x3pvcraxk60dyv9y4wmwcrc-gcc-wrapper-4.8.4/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No pkg-config found
Using strip version 2.23 found on system at:
/nix/store/yxg5zsjxp1l16xk7r23rayyc18fkxynk-binutils-2.23.1/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at:
/nix/store/blyc5sprbm85ph2fmksyhrqislp9j0im-gnutar-1.28/bin/tar
No uhc found
building
Building regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2...
Preprocessing library regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2...
[1 of 2] Compiling Text.Regex.TDFA.Text.Lazy ( Text/Regex/TDFA/Text/Lazy.hs, dist/build/Text/Regex/TDFA/Text/Lazy.o )

Text/Regex/TDFA/Text/Lazy.hs:77:9:
    Non type-variable argument
      in the constraint: Data.Array.Base.IArray a (Int, Int)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘go’ has the inferred type
      go :: forall t (a :: * -> * -> *) i.
            (Functor (a i), Num i, GHC.Arr.Ix i,
             Data.Array.Base.IArray a (Int, Int), Extract t) =>
            Int -> t -> [a i (Int, Int)] -> [a i (t, (Int, Int))]
    In the expression:
      let
        go i _ _ | i `seq` False = undefined
        go _i _t [] = []
        go i t (x : xs)
          = let ... in fmap trans x : seq t' (go (off0 + len0) t' xs)
      in go 0 source (matchAll regex source)
    In an equation for ‘matchAllText’:
        matchAllText regex source
          = let
              go i _ _ | i `seq` False = undefined
              go _i _t [] = ...
              go i t (x : xs) = ...
            in go 0 source (matchAll regex source)
builder for ‘/nix/store/69k8c7mvz64k08z9gabh7gmcn1i265rn-haskell-regex-tdfa-text-1.0.0.2.drv’ failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/lfjh66d015dkh9kr51h5871c7gqji5na-ghc-7.10.1.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/pdpsxp33mffmq72vhk5ig8bhrrdyq7p2-leksah.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of ‘/nix/store/pdpsxp33mffmq72vhk5ig8bhrrdyq7p2-leksah.drv’ failed
```

Comment: A breaking change in [GHC 7.10](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-10-1.html) - "GHC now checks that all the language extensions required for the inferred type signatures are explicitly enabled" - causes this package to break the build. Either use an older compiler, fix the package yourself, or wait till the maintainer fixes it.

Comment: Many thanks! I thought such breaking changes should not happen in nix derivations.

Comment: This is not 14.12, but rather 15.06 in development

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of `Leksah` compile successfully in the Nixpkgs `master` branch, i.e. at http://hydra.cryp.to/build/1410084. The `unstable` channel will have these updates soon. There are still some problems left to figure out with regard to how to run `Leksah` successfully on NixOS: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/10351 has more details.